# Remove or replace existing routes in RouteTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Preview 1 app and started to create some areas which contains their own routes.

I want to have a way to overwrite these routes in the main project. I can of course not add a new route with the same name. I can see the RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteBase item) but not sure how to use it.

```
//Need to remove "PostIndex" before adding it again
routes.MapAreaRoute(
                "OurAreaNameSpace",
                "PostIndex",
                "post/index/{currentPage}",
                new { controller = "Post", action = "Index", currentPage = "" },
                new string[] { "OurAreaNameSpace.Controllers" }
            );
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How do in this?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["PostIndex"]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took me several hour to find this solution. It works like a charm.