# how to remove a route from routes table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to remove a route from routes table. My code is:

```
var pages = from v in db.tblCmsPages where v.IsActive select v.PageUrlName;
foreach (string row in pages)
{
       routes.MapRoute(
       name: "mypages_"+row,
       url: row,
       defaults: new { controller = "MyPages", action = "en" },
       namespaces: new[] { "MGP_RealState.Controllers" }
       );
}
```

This is my routes collection. I just want to remove a particular route from this collection.
I have tried to select a particular route using linq just like

```
var myrouter = from v in System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes where v.? select v
```

not working

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Remove(?);
```

Comment: "Not working" is not very good explanation of a problem... Plus you are not actually showing code related to removal (compared to code you show for building routes). Please try to clarify what you tried. Otherwise it may end up duplicate of something like [Remove or replace existing routes in RouteTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417895/remove-or-replace-existing-routes-in-routetable).

Comment: There is a collection of routers. I just want to remove sum routers form that collection by using sum filter. i was try linq to filter but not working. is there any way to filter and remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just we need to create an object of route.

```
//Create the object of particular router
var rr = new System.Web.Routing.Route(tblcmspage.PageUrlName, new MvcRouteHandler())
            {
                Defaults = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "MyPages", action = "en" }),
                DataTokens = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { namespaces = new[] { "MGP_RealState.Controllers" } })
            };

//delete the router                
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Remove(rr);
```